# How to bind to a nested class wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a view model called FieldViewModel:

```
public class FieldViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Field m_field;
    public Field FieldData
    {
        get { return m_field; }
        set
        {
            m_field = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FieldData");
        }
    }
```

and the Field class:

```
public class Field : INotifyPropertyChanged
{     

    public List<string> SqlTypes
    {
        get { return Enum.GetNames(typeof(SqlDbType)).ToList(); }
    }


    private string m_FieldName = null;
    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return m_FieldName; }
        set
        {
            m_FieldName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FieldName");
        }
    }

    private string m_FieldType = null;
    public string FieldType
    {
        get { return m_FieldType; }
        set
        {
            m_FieldType = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FieldType");
        }
    }

    private bool m_NullAllow = false;
    public bool NullAllow
    {
        get { return m_NullAllow; }
        set
        {
            m_NullAllow = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("NullAllowsChecked");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The Xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FieldData.SqlTypes}" SelectionChanged="cmbField_Selected" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="5,5,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBox Width="120" Height="20" Text="{Binding FieldType}" Margin="0,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

now in the xaml i want to bind the variables of the Field Class but i can't see them

I tried some thing but nothing works, if i put the variables of the Field Class inside the FieldViewModel it works good.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example which works for me:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="czesciTable" ItemsSource="{Binding model.list}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Model model { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        model = new Model();
    }
}
```

And model:

```
public class Model 
{
    public List<String> list { get; set; }

    public Model()
    {
        list = new List<string>();

        list.Add("Item1");
        list.Add("Item2");
        list.Add("Item3");
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Or ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding model.list}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it didn't work for me, i already tried the suggestion with the combo box but still didn't work what do you think i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question was mainly correct. It was only missing the initialization of the Field Class.