# Xamarin Forms ListView Data Binding nested objects

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have simple Page with ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="ForecastView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding mainData.Temperature}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

I'm trying to bind nested property by using `.` to access it. My item source:

```
private ObservableCollection<ForecastData> forecast = new ObservableCollection<ForecastData>();
```

I'm setting it in constructor:

```
ForecastView.ItemsSource = forecast;
```

My model is looking like this:

```
public class ForecastData
    {
        public MainData mainData;
.....
public class MainData
    {
        public double Temperature;
...
```

After REST call my list is populated by elements (I can select them), but text property is blank. Can You help me figure out what is wrong. I have tried everything and nothing helps (I have read all similar question on Stack Overflow).

Comment: "Tamarin forms"

Comment: Try to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985634/xamarin-forms-databinding-separator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041542/how-to-bind-to-a-nested-class-wpf and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546347/how-to-use-nested-class-in-wpf-xaml.

Comment: you can only bind to public properties (with getters and setters) not public variables or methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to bind to a public field.

You can only bind to properties.

So change:

```
public MainData mainData;
```

To:

```
public MainData mainData { get; set; }
```

And it should work!

Also for `Temperature` of course.

Comment: I love You Gerald!

Comment: Well thank you! I've stared at it for sometime myself as well, after that you never forget!

Comment: Yes, full two days of nerves. Now I will remember forever!

Comment: How to bind information when MainData model has subclass which is a list?